# Mostrar una lista de items en horizontal Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode, uitableview

Estoy realizando una app que muestra la información meteorológica.

Tengo la vista dividida en 3 apartados:

1- Un Uiview con información del tiempo de hoy

2- Un UITableView con los días siguientes del tiempo

3- Una tabla horizontal con el tiempo por horas para el día de hoy(Aquí el problema)

He utilizado la librería `ASHorizontalScrollView` pero todos los items quedan en horizontal.
Me explico: Lo que quiero es que salga un pequeño icono con la hora y la temperatura, por cada hora. El problema es que no me queda uno debajo de otro, sino todo en horizontal.

Deberían de salir todos los items en horizontal, pero dentro de cada item, los 3 elemento, uno debajo de otro.

Conocéis alguna librería o un código para que funcione mas o menos como he explicado?

Os dejo un ejemplo del código:

```
    let horizontalScrollView:ASHorizontalScrollView = ASHorizontalScrollView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, vistaScroll.frame.size.width-12, 50.0))
    horizontalScrollView.leftMarginPx = 0
    horizontalScrollView.miniMarginPxBetweenItems = 0
    horizontalScrollView.miniAppearPxOfLastItem = 0
    horizontalScrollView.uniformItemSize = CGSizeMake(50, 50)
        //this must be called after changing any size or margin property of this class to get acurrate margin
    horizontalScrollView.setItemsMarginOnce()
        var valorArray = "01"
        for index in 1...24 {
            if index < 10 {
                valorArray = "0" + String(index)
            }
            else {
                valorArray = String(index)
            }
            let estado = currentArticleToDisplay.estadoCielo[valorArray]
            let label = UILabel()
            let labelHora = UILabel()
            let img = UIImageView()
            let url:NSURL? = NSURL(string:currentArticleToDisplay.icono[estado!]!)
            let imageRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
            // Fire off the request to download it
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(imageRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response, data, error) in
                // Assign the data to the imageview
                img.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            })
            label.text = currentArticleToDisplay.temperatura[valorArray]
            labelHora.text = valorArray
            let vista = UIView()
            vista.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50.0)
            vista.addSubview(label)
            vista.addSubview(labelHora)
            vista.addSubview(img)
            horizontalScrollView.addItem(img)
            horizontalScrollView.addItem(label)
            horizontalScrollView.addItem(labelHora)

        }
    vistaScroll.addSubview(horizontalScrollView)
```

Actualmente esta asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que esta dentro del circulo azul seria un item. lo que quiero es que en vez de salir el sol, la temperatura y la hora en linea, salga uno debajo de otro

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿Podrías hacer un pequeño croquis o similar para entender qué necesitas?

Comment: He añadido una imagen de ejemplo @mhergon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No utilices librerías externas para tan simple tarea. La mejor forma de organizar lo que necesitas es de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma, será todo nativo y tendrás el máximo control sobre los tamaños, `AutoLayout`, etc
La celda del `UICollectionView` hazla o bien en un `XIB` aparte o bien en el `StoryBoard` directamente.

Comment: Gracias, lo probaré ahora haber si funciona

Comment: Me ha funcionado perfecto, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que deberías usar un `UICollectionView`, no veo la necesidad de usar una librería aparte, puedes crear una celda en el storyboard y organizar los elementos de forma vertical o de la forma que quieras y colocar ese collectionView dentro de el UIView o UITableView.

Answer (score -1):

Utilizaría un UICollectionView solamente con diferentes tipos de celdas. Hay que tener cuidado a la hora de interactuar con varios componentes tal y como son UICollectionView dentro de un UITableView por temas de rendimiento.

Aún así, lo que nunca haría es utilizar una librería para implementar la vista que quieres hacer, ya que UIKit provee componentes nativos para ello.

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/40838)

Comment: Considero que se está dando una solución a nivel general a lo que propone en la pregunta.